# Why did it fail when I updated the database parameters?

Tags: cnosdb

cnosdb version 2.3.2

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" -u "root:" http://cnosdb-query-svc:8902/api/v1/sql?tenant=Tenant2Suborg2 -d "alter database monitor set ttl '10d' replica 2"  
{"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected end of statement, found: replica"}
```

according to docs: https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html#drop-database.
with cnosdb-cli:

```
public ❯ alter database monitor set ttl '10d' replica 2;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected end of statement, found: replica"}
```

Comment: Your statement mush finish with a semi colon.

Comment: @EricMartin I updated the execution results in cnosdb-cli and it is not a semicolon problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one parameter can be changed at a time